# Animation is lagging and stopping

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, game-development, animator

It's a 2D platformer game. Animations transitions were set up in the Animator window, but unfortunately, when the player encounters an obstacle, the animation stops. What could be the reason?
There is no problem with animation transitions.

[image]

Comment: do you have code to stop anything on impact?